# B-Bone Rig, moving branches

Tags: rigging

[image]

Why do I get this issue when I do a rig? I don't want this stringy stuff happening. I'm learning how to use Inverse Kinematics to make branches move in the wind.

Comment: it's probably because your weight painting gone wrong. the weights of the vertices decide, what parts of the meshes will be influenced by moving your bone. I strongly recommend watching some basic rigging tutorials for that.

Comment: Thanks, I started from scratch, and the problem did not occur a second time.